# How to not show menu included in application.html.erb on some urls in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have included an html menu in `application.html.erb` which is showing it on all the view templates, I was wondering how can I NOT show on some pages ?

like `if path == HOME || "/page/1"`

Then,

Do not show the menu else show it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an instance variable in the actions where you don't want the menu to appear, for example `@hide_menu`

Then, you can filter it in your view :

```
<% unless @hide_menu %>
...
<% end %>
```

If you have a lot of variables to do this, for lots of bits of code, you can use a hash, like `@config` for example, and initialize it in your application controller :

#### Application Controller

```
before_filter :init_config

def init_config
  @config = {...}
end
```

#### View

```
<% unless @config[:hide_menu] %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, just one thing, how to use @hide_menu with  <% if user_signed_in? %> ? I tried  <% if user_signed_in? && !@hide_menu %> but it didn't worked

Comment: @iCyborg !@hide_menu should work, have you set "@hide_menu = true" in the action in your controller? What error you get?

Comment: @Sinetris - Thanks, I was not using "true" :) now it is working. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current url with request.fullpath, so you just can check if you are in home or wherever with if request.fullpath == HOME for example.

Answer (score 1):

First use the **menu code** in `application_controller` in a `before_filter` as-

**Application Controller:**

```
before_filter :show_menus

 def show_menus

      # the menu stuff you want to show
  end
```

Then you can use following inside your any controller where the `before_filter` should not get executed or where you don't want to show your menus-

**Other Controller:**

```
skip_before_filter :show_menus
```

You can even ignore the `before_filter` for any action you want.
For example-

```
skip_before_filter :show_menus, :only => [:logout]
```

The above line will not show your menus for the **logout action** for the controller inside which you mentioned this line(Other Controller here).

**Note:** This procedure will avoid the **ugly looking repeated if else statements** for show/hide menu for every action like -

```
if action_name

#show menu

else

#hide menu

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to hide the menu based on some logic, you can use the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174210/how-to-not-show-menu-included-in-application-html-erb-on-some-urls-in-rails/15174242#15174242) by [Intrepidd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624551/intrepidd).
If you need to hide the menu only in a few places or show something else instead of the menu you can use `content_for`

**/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= content_for?(:menu) ? yield(:menu) : (render 'layouts/menu') %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**/app/views/layouts/_menu.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %> | <%= link_to "Pages", pages_path %>
```

**/app/views/pages/index.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :menu do %>
  this can be whatever you want, even a blank string
<% end %>

here the content for pages/index
```

Comment: Thanks, btw, I don't think !@hide_menu is the correct operator (ansewr of intrepidd), can you give me the correct syntax for <% if user_signed_in? && !@hide_menu %>